# Do my crew members with negative stats decrease further upon leveling?

Tags: runescape

I've been working my way through the player owned ports minigame in Runescape.  I just recruited my first "Crows Nest Sniper" who came with a perk titled Slow, which sets his speed stat to -80.  This really isn't that bad, since -80 is rather small for the speed stat, however when a crew member levels, all of their stats increase by 10% of the base value.

When he levels, will this stat decrease further (in this case to -88), or will it remain the same or possibly even increase?  I'd like to know before I invest in him just to have him slow my ship down further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stat appears to remain the same.

After leveling up this crew member some, his speed stat still remains at -80.  It appears that negative traits such as Slow do not continue to decrease as the crew member levels up and are locked in at the base value.